R dplyr mutate across columns - pick first value in several columns that is greater than another
I have a dataset that looks like this but with much more t_i columns:
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3,4), "date" = c(4,8,2,5), 
             "t_1" = c(NA,9,NA,4), "t_2" = c(NA,10,NA,5),
             "t_3" = c(NA,12,NA,6),"t_4" = c(NA,16,NA,8))

# id date t_1 t_2 t_3 t_4
# 1    4  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 2    8   9  10  12  NA
# 3    2  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 4    5   4   5   6   8

In my data, for each individuals "id", I have a date in the column "date" and I have other dates in columns "t_1,...,t_x" that are in chronological order. When one t_i is NA then all subsequent t_i+1,...,t_x are NA (non available). In the example data above, I chose to replace the dates by numeric values to keep it simple.
What I want: create a column to my data, let's say "entry" that takes the first value of the columns t_1, ...,t_x for which
"date"<"t_i" else NA.
In my example, the result would be:
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3,4), "date" = c(4,8,2,5), 
             "entry"=c(NA,9,NA,6),"t_1" = c(NA,9,NA,4), 
             "t_2" = c(NA,10,NA,5),"t_3" = c(NA,12,NA,6),
             "t_4" = c(NA,NA,NA,8))

# id date entry t_1 t_2 t_3 t_4
# 1    4    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 2    8     9   9  10  12  NA
# 3    2    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 4    5     6   4   5   6   8
    

I have the feeling that I could use across or if_any or if_all in dplyr mutate but I can't find the right code! Your help would be more than welcome!
Thank you

Is groping by id important or are there no multiple occurences of an id?

You can first reshape your data into a "long" format, then use some indexing to get the correct "t_i" values for entry by id, then transform back to your "wide" format.
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(-1, -2)) %>% 
  mutate(entry = min(value[date < value]), .by = id) %>% 
  pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 4 × 7
     id  date entry   t_1   t_2   t_3   t_4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     2     8     9     9    10    12    16
3     3     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4     4     5     6     4     5     6     8


Thanks for this solution. Funny thing is that my data were beforehand in long format with the two types of events, one linked to "date" and the other to "t_i", in the same column. I separated the events and created the wide format. I will change my strategy and apply your solution
